# common library nuget package integration with tfsbuild server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

This question is a follow on from:: [how to handle a common library in TFS & share dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000894/how-to-handle-a-common-library-in-tfs-share-dlls)

I have decided to go with the approach where I use a nuget package to share my common library with other projects. I have integrated this with tfs build server where a package is created and moved to a shared location when a build completes.

I am a little confused how this might work locally. In particular, lets say I work on the common library locally, build it, package created. I want to use this in my local project. Do I install the package from where the package was created locally? Or on the tfs build server? My preference is, local development references the local package, but when I check it in to tfs build server, it picks the package from the common library package location in tfs build. I know this is confusing, but want the perfect package distribution system!

One other thing, how easy is it the debug the package locally, when I make changes to common, I would like to be able debug the local package if possible. Is it possible?

Comment: Get familiar with [NuGetter](http://nugetter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I am familiar with it, but how can this help me locally?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is push the latest "common" package to a central package repository (self-hosted or www.myget.org) by your TFS build server. You want to make sure that the build server also pushes symbols packages (for example, to SymbolSource.org)

Afterwards, every project can consume this common package from the package repository created. Debugging symbols will be downloaded automatically when needed by Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I am not familiar with pushing symbol packages with nuget, please explain?

Comment: When you build a package, it can generate 2 artifacts: a .symbols.nupkg and .nupk. The symbols package can be uploaded to a different feed and configured in VS2010/VS2012 to retrieve symbols while debugging. Here are some resources: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2011/11/16/why-everyone-should-be-using-a-symbol-server & http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Blog/View/2012-08-22/How_SymbolSource_integrates_with_NuGet_and_MyGet & http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package